# How to fix vanilla comments extra iframe space

Tags: plugins, php, customization, comments

I am using the new vanilla comments on wordpress with my self hosted vanilla forums, but on every page, there is unnecesary iframe space. I was wondering how to fix that. My site is [here](http://www.applemonster.co) and my forums are [here](http://forums.applemonster.co). Between the submit comment and comments by vanilla link.

Comment: Link to your forums is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## UPDATE

The frame element has a height of 1000px. I am not sure which file generates the comment form, but the height seems to be in that file. Simply delete `height=1000px` to remove the space.

Also, if you want to remove the Vanilla credit and link, add `.vanilla-credit {display:none !important}` to your style sheet.

## ORIGINAL

I believe you are referring to the large space between the bottom of your post and the "Leave Comments" title to the comment textarea.

If so, there is a pretty large bottom margin in the `.post` class in your style sheet. You can remove it by changing it to `margin:0`

Comment: no, the "post comment" and "comments by vanilla link", but what you stated can come in handy on a future project

Comment: I updated my answer above.